# Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didnt respond within 10 seconds. (Firestore)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am having this problem in a new React-Native project even though I do have a good internet connection.

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.13.2): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.

this is my Firebase config file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

import {
    API_KEY,
    AUTH_DOMAIN,
    DATABASE_URL,
    PROJECT_ID,
    STORAGE_BUCKET,
    MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    APP_ID,
    MEASUREMENTID
} from "react-native-dotenv";


const config = {
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    authDomain: AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: APP_ID,
    measurementId: MEASUREMENTID
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)
import "firebase/firestore";

export const firestore = firebase.firestore()
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the good credential with react-native-dotenv? Can you do a console log of all the data ( API_KEY etc ) to see if one is undefined ?

Comment: @CR7 I just tried and it prints all of them. No undefined.

Comment: @CR7 I just tested by placing the keys directly in the config const but the same error. Any idea?

Comment: It's weird, can you show more code ? Like where you use firestore.

Comment: @CR7 screw it, I decided to switch to react-native-firebase and it WORKS!

Comment: can you show an example of how you did it with react-native-firebase? I'm using firebase-9.6.6 and I'm getting the same error!!!!